# Android Studio Configuration and Emulator set up

Tags: android-studio

I would like to use Android Studio as I start to learn about android development and I don't know exactly about necessary configuration in Android Studio. Would you like to guide about Android Studio Configuration including emulator set up ? Thanks.

Comment: you should learn from here https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html. Welcome from SO. This is not a type question for this site. You should search on GOOGLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are working on Windows and downloaded the Android Studio and installed the JDX-7/8.
Click on the .exe file. It will by default install Nougat (Android 7) SDK's. If you want some other SDK then you have to do so by selecting them from SDK Manager.

Refer the following link: https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

About SDK Manager refer this: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

During the setup it will ask for emulator, select the device which you want and the default configurtion is loaded by Android Studio. If you want to change the device them go to AVD Manager and select the device.
(Note): In order to use emulator virtualization has to be enabled on your machine.

Refer the link: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 0):

This would be a best place to start

https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html